# How to force HttpURLConnection request to wait for full response?

Tags: java, android, download

I am trying to get a JSON response using this code.
it works fine for short responses (20 to 30 lines) but cuts off in middle of longer ones.

```
final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) { throw new Exception(); }
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String inline; StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
while ((inline = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inline);
}
in.close();
Log.d(TAG, "getJson: {"+url.toString()+"}\n"+response.toString());
return response.toString();
```

Sample of the logcat output showing cutoff json [here](https://gist.github.com/sh7411usa/7863bbab55e1f8939172ef3c89b143d6).

How can I force it to always download the full response?

#### Edit:

It seems from the comments that this question generated, as well as further testing, that there is nothing inherent or lacking in the code that is causing the server to truncate, but that this is an android specific problem.
Can anyone, A) identify why long responses (use example link above) truncate specifically on android (whether from above code, or in android browser), and B) - (the real question) is there a way to programatically overcome the issue?

Comment: It is truncated because the server truncates it, not the Java code. Go ahead, try that URL in a web browser. You'll see the response is truncated there too.

Comment: Works for me, no truncation, whole JSON array printed. Tested on JDK11 :).

Comment: @Andreas when i try it in a web browser, i get the full response. though on my android device ( a different internet connection  ) it gets cut off. Maybe it has to do with connection speed?

Comment: Don't know, but if the Android device web browser has the same issue, you know it's not the Java code, so there is nothing you can do in the code to fix it.

Comment: @andreas - If its a timeout issue though, that's enforced by android, maybe i can override it. I'm just not sure how. Also - why in the world would android block me from getting the full response, when a PC web browser works fine?

Comment: @hradecek - as per above comments, do you mind sharing what platform and environment did you tested on?

Comment: Tested on Windows 10 machine using "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)".
I have only replaced `Log` by `System.out.println()` in your sample code and added url from github gist and everything is working fine.

Comment: thanks. as per above, have edited the question , as this seems to be an android specific issue